# FLUTTER Snackbar or toast below Appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I know implementing a snackbar or a toast in flutter is pretty simple, but has anyone figured out how to make the snackbar pop out from the top UNDER the appbar, just like the green 'Clocked In' pop up in the image below?

[image: t]

Comment: did you find the solution for the same? Could you please share, I am looking for the same.

Comment: @Araju did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar library.
Then you can customize your flushbar like this:

```
Flushbar(
  flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
)
```

Comment: Flushbar doesn't avoids bottomnavbar and appbar I have tried myself and filled an issue also about this.

Comment: yea looks like Flushbar plugin shows above the appbar :/ ....maybe a solution would be to get the appbar's height then use that as a margin?